# T4MVC - different controllers conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, t4mvc

I have actions

```
public virtual ActionResult Show(string userId)
```

and

```
public virtual ActionResult Show(int groupId)
```

In Global.asax I have

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Group_Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{groupId}",
                MVC.Groups.Show()
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "UserProfile_Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{userId}",
                MVC.Profile.Show()
            );
```

Now when I request for `group/show/...` it works fine. But when I call `Profile/Show/...` parameter is null. But if I remove `UserProfile_Default` then both works but profile URL contains question mark for parameter (and I want it clean like `.../profile/show/5678`)
It seams that somehow one route block another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these instead:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Group_Default",
    "Group/{action}/{groupId}",
    new { controller = "Group" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "UserProfile_Default",
    "Profile/{action}/{userId}",
    new { controller = "Profile" }
);
```

For future reference, the route debugger is a really good tool to see exactly what's going on with your routing and which URLs are hitting what actions: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx